# Is it possible to highlight certain rows of code in visual studio?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

At the moment I'm working in a file with perhaps 1000 lines of code (HTML/JS). Lets say that there are three or four of these lines that are extra important, that I keep coming back to, to look up things. I find it a bit frustrating that it takes a few seconds every time I want to find one of these rows while scrolling through the code.

If it had been C# code, I could have set a break point at each important row, to make it easier to spot them when I scroll through the code, but that is not possible since this is an HTML-file.

Is there some way to highlight certain rows in Visual Studio, to make it easier to find them while scrolling through the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the bookmark functionality. Some info can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc3ed5eh.aspx).

It can be a bit cumbersome at first, but once you learn the appropriate [shortcuts](http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Visual-Studio_2010.html#link_2) to bookmark / unbookmark / go to next bookmark it will make navigating your code a bit easier.

Comment: That seems to be exactly what I'm looking for, I'll give that a try straight away. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

How about highlighting these important areas with well named Regions?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a1ybwek(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Regions does not work in the HTML-editor, or am I wrong there?

Comment: Using regions are contentious, and they're not supported for .js files natively. The plug I've found for it slows down monstrously when you hit about 1k lines.